# Are these methods being used on the following objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I have some questions in regards to a snippet of C# code. Below is an example for OxyPlot (it's not important to know this, but I thought I'd say it anyways) for plotting a heat map.

```
HeatMapSeries heatMapSeries = new HeatMapSeries();
heatMapSeries.X0 = 0.5;
heatMapSeries.X1 = 1.5;
heatMapSeries.Y0 = 0.5;
heatMapSeries.Y1 = 2.5;
heatMapSeries.Interpolate = false;

heatMapSeries.Data = new Double[2, 3];
heatMapSeries.Data[0, 0] = 0;
heatMapSeries.Data[0, 1] = 0.2;
heatMapSeries.Data[0, 2] = 0.4;
heatMapSeries.Data[1, 0] = 0.1;
heatMapSeries.Data[1, 1] = 0.3;
heatMapSeries.Data[1, 2] = 0.2;
```

You are creating a new `heatMapSeries` object using the `HeatMapSeries()` constructor. Next, the operation `heatMapSeries.X0`, `heatMapSeries.X1`, `heatMapSeries.Y0`, `heatMapSeries.Y1` are being assigned new values, which I am highly certain contain default instance variables inside the OxyPlot `HeatMapSeries()` constructor. Now, my question is, what exactly is the `.X0`, `.X1`, `Y0`, et cetera, doing?

In Java, `bigBrownYak.calculateWeight()` would be using a `calculateWeight()` method on the `bigBrownYak` object. So are things like `.X0` , methods?

Next, `heatMapSeries.Data = new Double[2,3]` is creating a new `Double` multi-dimensional array, which I understand, but what is `.Data` doing to `heatMapSeries`? Is `Data` an instance variable within the `heatMapSeries` constructor object?

Sorry for the rather rudimentary questions.

Comment: Those are called "properties" in C#. Please look it up. A property named `X` is similar to `set_X` and `get_X` methods in Java.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure why this deserves to be closed. I made sure I clarified all the research I put in (despite it being an understanding of another language). It's not a one-liner question demanding to have answers given like some other questions asked by new users. I just don't get it.

Comment: Closing doesn't mean you're a bad person - it means that the question doesn't deserve to continue on the site. Your question is basically, "what is this syntactic construct", and the answer is "it's a property". We don't really need 10,000 duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

They can be compared (but not entirely) with getters & setters in Java. Except they work in the same manner as a public field in Java.

Implementation can look like this:

```
public string X0 { get; set; } // Auto implemented property

private string field;

public string X0 { 
     get { return field * 2; } 
     set { field = value; }
} // Custom property with backing field
```

Usage:

```
// Getting value
var x = someObject.X0;

// Setting value
someObject.XO = "lala";
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for the clarification.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at the official [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Jeroen's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20432034/643085), those are properties in C#, something that java lacks entirely and tries to imitate using a `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` convention, which is just awful.

I'd also like to add that this code is particularily "non-C#"-like:

```
        HeatMapSeries heatMapSeries = new HeatMapSeries();
        heatMapSeries.X0 = 0.5;
        heatMapSeries.X1 = 1.5;
        heatMapSeries.Y0 = 0.5;
        heatMapSeries.Y1 = 2.5;
        heatMapSeries.Interpolate = false;
```

In C#, you use the [Object Initializer Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to simplify these kind of constructs:

```
        var heatMapSeries = new HeatMapSeries 
                            {
                               X0 = 0.5,
                               X1 = 1.5,
                               Y0 = 0.5,
                               Y1 = 2.5,
                               Interpolate = false
                            };
```

Also notice the usage of the [var keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) to avoid typing the `HeatMapSeries` type name twice in the same line of code.

Conclusion: Yes, C# is much better than java.

Comment: The code originally was `var heatMapSeries`. I simply replaced it (like I would in Java). I'm in a weird point of having my legs in two different language standards..

Comment: Also, it appears, if I were to do this in Java, it would be something like this: `heatMapSeries.X1(1.5)`, is that correct?

Comment: @thegreencabbage forget java, it's a dinosaur language that refuses to grow up and evolve and forces you to remain in the 90's. It's not the 90's anymore. Use C#.

Comment: Well, at the moment, I'm not here to discuss which language is better, but I appreciate the input.

Comment: @thegreencabbage yes, that in java would be something like `heatMapSeries.setX1(1.5);`, but that's just because java is a horrible language that does not have real properties and has this fake thing they call properties but are actually methods, and are called with the same syntax as any other method.